# размещение двух div блоков в одну строку

Tags: html, css

Не получается разместить всплывающую подсказку оформленную в виде знака вопроса в одну строчку с текстом http://www.rimeks.ru/price/moyka-avtomobilya/ прошу помощи более опытных верстальщиков.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.block {   
    padding: 25px;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    background: #ccc;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
a[data-tooltip] { 
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
a[data-tooltip]:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
a[data-tooltip]:after,
a[data-tooltip]:before {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    font-size: .75em;
    position: absolute;
}
a[data-tooltip]:after {
    border-top: 0.5em solid #222;
    border-top: 0.5em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    border-left: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-right: 0.5em solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    left: 40%;
    width: 0;
}
a[data-tooltip]:before {    
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    color: #f6f6f6;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
a[data-tooltip]:hover:after,
a[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
    display: block;
}
a[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
    top: -0.5em;
}
a[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
    top: -2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  <a href="#" data-tooltip="Я подсказка 1!">?</a> text text text text text <a href="#" data-tooltip="Я подсказка 2!">?</a> text text text text text </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы разместить два элемента div на одной сточке вам нужно сделать их блочно строчными:

```
<style>
    div {
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
<div>tekst1</div>
<div>tekst2</div>
```